# Can't run tests with Mocha on Express.js app

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

I am trying to setup mocha to test an ExpressJs app.

When I run tests using `npm test` I got the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (/myapp/bin/www:11:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.cls_wrapMethod (/Users/nathanzylbersztejn/git/airdesk-api/node_modules/newrelic/lib/shimmer.js:230:38)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nathanzylbersztejn/git/airdesk-api/controllers/session.js:13:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.cls_wrapMethod (/Users/nathanzylbersztejn/git/airdesk-api/node_modules/newrelic/lib/shimmer.js:230:38)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nathanzylbersztejn/git/airdesk-api/app.js:10:25)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nathanzylbersztejn/git/airdesk-api/test/test.js:5:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at /Users/nathanzylbersztejn/git/airdesk-api/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:185:27
at Array.forEach (native)
at Mocha.loadFiles (/Users/nathanzylbersztejn/git/airdesk-api/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:182:14)
at Mocha.run (/Users/nathanzylbersztejn/git/airdesk-api/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:394:31)
at loadAndRun (/Users/nathanzylbersztejn/git/airdesk-api/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:349:22)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nathanzylbersztejn/git/airdesk-api/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:366:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
at node.js:814:3
```

Where `/myapp/bin/www:11:5` refers to the following line:

```
var app = require('../app')
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000); // <- this line 
     ^
```

The app works well, so it's not related to the app setup.
Any idea?

Comment: what does ```console.log(app)``` show when you run the test?

Comment: then your problem is in exporting the app. ```require('../app')``` is just returning an empty object for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First guess is you have a circular dependency, which node handles by returning an empty object until the circle is finished. Do you do something like `require("./bin/www");` inside `app.js`?
If you post `app.js` and `bin/www` we should be able to confirm.

Second guess is `app.js` just isn't getting the commonjs exports correct.

I'm also pretty sure you should be able to test your express app with supertest loading just `app.js` and leaving `bin/www` just for when you launch a real server instance.